# Setting up a test server with Gulp, PHP and browser-sync

Tags: php, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-connect-php

I've inherited a static project using Gulp (which i'm new to) and the client is asking to add server side functionality. I'm trying to perform local development with php and gulp as well as using browser-sync.

I have checked that php is installed as is the gulp-connect-php dependency. This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var connect     = require('gulp-connect-php');
var concat  = require('gulp-concat');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var nano    = require('gulp-cssnano');
var browserSync      = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);

gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
  });

  gulp.watch(["./build/**/*.html","./build/**/*.php", "./build/**/*.js","./build/img/**/*"]).on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});



gulp.task('watch', ['html-include', 'php', 'css', 'scripts', 'assets', 'fonts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.html', ['html-include']);
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('./source/img/**/*', ['assets']);
    gulp.watch('./source/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
});

gulp.task('html-include', function() {    
    return gulp.src('./source/**/*.html') // Ignores template files
        .pipe(changed('./source/**/*.html'))      
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('php', function() {    
    return gulp.src('./source/**/*.php') // Ignores template files
        .pipe(changed('./source/**/*.php'))      
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/js/*.js')
        .pipe(changed('./build/js/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});

gulp.task('assets', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/img/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('./build/img/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('./build/fonts/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/css/*.css')    
        .pipe(concat('cic.min.css'))
        .pipe(nano()) // Only enable for deployment, too slow for development
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

When I try and run gulp with this file I get the following error:

*Task 'browser-sync' is not in your gulpfile  Please check the
documentation for proper gulpfile formatting*

As I say I'm new to gulp and just want to get a test server up and running for local development.

Any suggestions on how to reformat my code to work.

Thanks

Update - 
Ok I've managed to get the server up and running with the following Gulpfile code:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var changed     = require('gulp-changed');
var phpConect   = require('gulp-connect-php');
var nano        = require('gulp-cssnano');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var bs          = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);

gulp.task('php', function() {
    phpConect.server({ base: 'build/', port: 8010, keepalive: true});
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['php','watch'], function() {
    bs({
        proxy: '127.0.0.1:8010',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
    gulp.watch(["./build/**/*.html","./build/**/*.php","./build/**/*.js","./build/img/**/*"]).on('change', bs.reload);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['html-include', 'php-files', 'sass', 'scripts', 'assets', 'fonts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.html', ['html-include']);
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.php', ['php-files']);
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./source/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./source/img/**/*', ['assets']);
    gulp.watch('./source/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
});

gulp.task('html-include', function() {    
    return gulp.src('./source/**/*.html') // Ignores template files  
        .pipe(changed('./build/**/*'))  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('php-files', function() {    
    return gulp.src('./source/**/*.php') // Ignores template files
        .pipe(changed('./build/**/*'))      
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/js/*.js')
        .pipe(changed('./build/js/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});

gulp.task('assets', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/img/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('./build/img/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('./build/fonts/**/*')) // Ignore unchanged files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./source/sass/*.scss') 
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(nano()) // Only enable for deployment, too slow for development
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
        .pipe(bs.stream());
});
```

But now when I preview my files in safai (and only safari) the video files aren't being served at all., even though they're there. Is this a known issue with php/gulp development in a local environment?

Dan

Comment: Can you make sure browserSync actually works? have you tried running gulp serve to make sure of this?

Comment: I have got browserSync to work, as i have modified the gulpfile.js and it was working originally.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is that you don't actually have any task called 'browser-sync' so its legit that you have a warning telling you thatt the task doesn't exist. Either you need to rename your task to : gulp.task('default', ['connect-sync']); or call your task 'browser-sync' instead of 'connect-sync'. Tell me if that works

Comment: Hi I've got it to work, please see my comments above about the new issue with video files and safari from localhost

Comment: I have no idea about that. So its working in other browsers? any error logged in the console?